# Ставим background-image

Tags: html, css, javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня есть `background-image`, размером `1600x1200px`. Хочу сделать так, чтобы она появлялась на экране так, чтобы ее центр совпадал с центром экрана, а то что не влезает отрезалоь бы. Как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет надо так:

```
background: fixed #FFFFFF url(../images/bg.jpg) center no-repeat;
```

Comment: ps: незабудте поставить галочку

Comment: @Rules, я поставил. Можешь поверить.

Answer (score 1):

```
background: url(bg.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте css background-position с отрицательным значением
Подробнее [здесь](http://www.ruled.ru/background-css.html), например